# Dependency inject a continuation library C++

Tags: c++, templates, dependency-injection, c++17

How do I dependency inject a class that I can't describe without a template.

Problem: I'm writing a library where I would like to take a dependency on a continuation library from the host application aka library users rather than incorporating something like pplx as part of my library.

```
template<typename _ReturnType>
struct ITask
{
    template<typename _ThenReturnType>
    virtual std::shared_ptr<ITask<_ThenReturnType>> Then(const std::function<_ThenReturnType(_ReturnType)>&& func) = 0;
};

struct ITaskFactoryService
{
    template<typename _TaskReturnType>
    virtual std::shared_ptr<ITask<_TaskReturnType>> CreateTask(const std::function<_TaskReturnType()>) = 0;
};

struct IHostServices
{
    virtual std::shared_ptr<ITaskFactoryService> TaskFactoryService() noexcept = 0;
};
```

I know this is not possible in C++ what I'm looking for is a design solution to my bigger problem. I was hoping the host app (library consumer) can implement this and pass it to my library. I'm doing this because different hosts might have different continuation libraries.

Comment: I could pass around void pointers I guess, but seems very dirty to me :(

Comment: By library you mean some headers / source files - or really something like a dll?

Comment: You can't use virtual with templates...

Comment: Could you add some more info about your needs?

Comment: I don't think the answer changes if it's header only, compiled from source of if it's a shared or static library. I think the example I've given could be used as pseudo code to understand what I'm trying to achieve. And yes the fact that I can't use virtual with templates is precisely why I'm trying to find the best way to dependency inject something whose exact types are not known before hand.

Comment: It changes the answer a bit with templates. To create code with templates those must be instantiated. Without explicit instantiation most of your code is not stored in your dll - you don't win something. But I understand you would be happy with regular C++ code. It must not be "easy" callable from C.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you, you want be able to replace your continuation library with another one. To do this you would like to write you own wrappers around them.

In general I think you should write more "C++-ish Code". ITask and so on look more "Java-Like" Code.

Usually you define properties / guarantees which are required for let's says "Task-Like-Types".

For example a Task-Like-Type must have a member function "Then" which accepts a Task-Like type and returns a new Task-Like-Type.

To test if a type is "Task-Like" you use typically Type-Traits which test your requirements. An alternative, more simple approach is to use "Type-Tags".

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/cPqh37) you can find some C++-ish Code which shows how to solve your design issue:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

//type tags
namespace MyContinuationLib
{
    class TaskLikeTypeTag{};
    class NoType{};
}

//traits
namespace MyContinuationLib
{
    //can be used for SFINAE
    template<
      typename T
    >
    class IsTaskLikeType
    {  
    public:
        static constexpr bool value = std::is_base_of_v<TaskLikeTypeTag, T>;
    };
}

//task factory
namespace MyContinuationLib
{
    template<
        template<typename...> typename TaskImplTemplate
    >
    class TaskFactory
    {
    };

    class HostServices;

    template<
        typename T
        ,typename UsedHostServices = HostServices
        ,typename PureT = std::remove_reference_t<T>
        ,typename = std::enable_if_t<
            !MyContinuationLib::IsTaskLikeType<PureT>::value
        >
        ,typename Dummy = void
    >
    auto ForceTaskLikeType(T&& callable)
    {
        using TaskFactory = typename UsedHostServices::TaskFactory;
        auto task = TaskFactory::CreateTask(callable);
        return task;
    }

    template<
        typename T
        ,typename PureT = std::remove_reference_t<T>
        ,typename = std::enable_if_t<
            MyContinuationLib::IsTaskLikeType<PureT>::value
        >
    >
    decltype(auto) ForceTaskLikeType(T&& callable)
    {
        return callable;
    }
}


//some TaskImplementation (you would need to define it's properties / what it should do!)

namespace MyContinuationLib
{
    template<typename...>
    class MyTask{};

    template<
        typename Callable
    >
    class MyTask<Callable> : public TaskLikeTypeTag
    {
    private:
        Callable callable; //e.g. a lambda or a std::function
    public:
        constexpr MyTask(const Callable& c) : callable(c){}
    public:
        template<
            typename CustomReturnType = NoType
            ,typename Invokable
            , typename InvokeResult = std::invoke_result_t<Invokable>
            , typename ReturnType = std::conditional_t<
                std::is_same_v<CustomReturnType, NoType>,
                InvokeResult,
                CustomReturnType
            >
            ,typename Result = MyTask<ReturnType, Invokable>
        >
        Result Then(Invokable&& func)
        {
            return Result(
                [&]{
                    this->operator();
                    return static_cast<ReturnType>(func());
                    //what ever...
                }
            );
        }

        constexpr void SomeOtherTaskLikeFkt(){
            callable();
            std::cout << "SomeOtherTaskLikeFkt...";
        }

        constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(){
            return callable();
        }
    };

    template<>
    class TaskFactory<MyTask>
    {
    public:
        template<
            typename Callable
        >
        constexpr static decltype(auto) CreateTask(Callable&& callable)
        {
            using PureCallable = std::remove_reference_t<Callable>;
            return MyTask<PureCallable>{ callable };
        }
    };
}

//TaskFactories
namespace MyContinuationLib
{
    class HostServices{
    public:
        //here we define what impl should be used!
        using TaskFactory = MyContinuationLib::TaskFactory<MyTask>;
    };
}

int main(){
    using namespace MyContinuationLib;

    auto task = ForceTaskLikeType([]{
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    });

    task.SomeOtherTaskLikeFkt();

    return 0;
}
```

If you do not understand the code or parts of it please ask.